# Inserting "$binary" key into mongodb from nodejs results in must not start with '$' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using node driver to add records to mongo.
I have a collection where one of the fields is: `{ "$binary": "base64 enconded binary" }`.

However a direct injection of the key starting with `$` results in error: `Error: key $binary must not start with '$'`

*Question:* how to handle this situation? Is there a javascript function I should call that will be interpreted by mongo as BSON binray function (like with the ISODate() - new Date() and NumberLong() -> Long())? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears that I have missed the function `Binary({buffer},{binary_type})`.
More on it: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html

My usage:

```
db.collection(coll).insert({
    "id" : rand1,
    "ReportData" : Binary("aaaaa", 0),
    ...
```